# How can I program my Azure Logic App to return a URL to its run results?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My logic app writes records to a database. I need one column in each record to contain a URL to the run results of my logic app. Is there an expression I can send to that column that will contain, for example, a url like this:

"https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/LogicAppsMonitorBlade/runid/%2Fsubscriptions%2F0ceab35e-487b-4437-9d78-69e688e7c007%2FresourceGroups%2FBibiBT-DevTestLogicApps%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Logic%2Fworkflows%2FProcessDelta-DEV%2Fruns%2F08585016034271140325372342996CU17"

?

Comment: You need to provide screenshots, we can't access your Azure Subscription.

Comment: I included that link only as an example of the string I need to build from withing the Logic App itself.

Answer (score 1):

Load this in to your tenant as a new LogicApp, it will show you the expression you need to use to retrieve the current Run ID ...

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_Workflow_Run_URL": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Workflow Run URL",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/LogicAppsMonitorBlade/runid/@{replace(workflow()['run']['id'], '/', '%2F')}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

... which is this ...

```
https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/LogicAppsMonitorBlade/runid/@{replace(workflow()['run']['id'], '/', '%2F')}
```

Comment: workflow()['run']['id']) was not very reliable. More often than not, it contained a string like :
/workflows/000964e8faff401c95e69bdae80cfc84/runs/08585015292550193107483557612CU26. 

The resultant url: 

https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/LogicAppsMonitorBlade/runid/%2Fworkflows%2F000964e8faff401c95e69bdae80cfc84%2Fruns%2F08585015292550193107483557612CU26

Rendered a run page with an empty canvas.

Comment: It’s the encoding of the URL, there appears to be a bug in LogicApps. If you look closely, I have a function that encases the property retrieval (encodeUriComponent) which disappears for me as well once you leave the screen. I have a workaround that I will include in my answer once I’m in front of my computer. The property is reliable, it’s the added encoding step that’s not. I’d suggest adopting my answer once I update it, your approach isn’t as foolproof (with all due respect)

Comment: My answer has been updated, I recommend you use it.  If MS ever change the second half of the URL, your approach will cease to work.

Comment: I think I've implemented your fix:
                "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "logicAppUrl",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/LogicAppsMonitorBlade/runid/@{replace(workflow()['run']['id'], '/', '%2F')}"
                        }

but the result:
https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/LogicAppsMonitorBlade/runid/%2Fworkflows%2F000964e8faff401c95e69bdae80cfc84%2Fruns%2F08585014354443924485279260770CU12

still renders empty

Comment: You get a different result to me which is baffling.  Your URL is shorter than what is produced for me and for me, it works.  The only way we could work out what is going wrong is if you created variable of type `object` and put the `workflow()` is expression in it and showed me what the result was.

Comment: I don't understand why the output from workflow()['run']['id'] doesn't include, e.g., subscriptions, resourceGroups, providers, etc?

Comment: {
            "name": "workflowObject",
            "type": "Object",
            "value": {
                "id": "/workflows/000964e8faff401c95e69bdae80cfc84",
                "name": "ProcessRmisDelta",
                "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
                "location": "centralus",
                "run": {
                    "id": "/workflows/000964e8faff401c95e69bdae80cfc84/runs/08585014350690569122403979401CU16",
                    "name": "08585014350690569122403979401CU16",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs"

Comment: Yep, weird, mind gives me this for the `run` property ...

{
  "run": {
    "id": "/subscriptions/6434d45e-44ac-4598-a34b-f6a43d04cf30/resourceGroups/rd-LogicApps/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/lgc-testApp/runs/08585015863566561369626710344CU10",
    "name": "08585015863566561369626710344CU10",
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs"
  }
}

It must have something to do with the region it's running in or something.  Here I was thinking I could help but this is a doozy!

Comment: Thanks for all the help. 

(I seem to have a real talent for doozies.)

Answer (score 0):

> I need one column in each record to contain a URL to the run results of my logic app. Is there an expression I can send to that column that will contain

Yes, you can do this using below **`design`**:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Checking if it got inserted or not:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally built my own expression:

concat('https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/LogicAppsMonitorBlade/runid/%2Fsubscriptions%2F',triggerOutputs()['headers']?['x-ms-workflow-subscription-id'],'%2FresourceGroups%2F',triggerOutputs()['headers']?['x-ms-workflow-resourcegroup-name'],'%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Logic%2Fworkflows%2F',workflow()['name'],'%2Fruns%2F',variables('runid'))